# What is the purpose of 「し」 in phrase 「私は緊{きん}張{ちょう}しすぎて」?

Tags: grammar

There is a phrase 「私は緊{きん}張{ちょう}しすぎて」.
Translates as:

> 私は - I
> 緊張 - nervous
> すぎて - too; exceedingly

But what is the purpose of 「し」 after 「緊張」?

Comment: Now that you know about し, you may want to go back and revisit your question about しながら.

Comment: Yes, indeed, thanks :) I somehow thought that しながら is one word, but it appears that this is する + ながら.

Comment: Where did you find "exceedingly"?

Comment: [Here](http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~jwb/cgi-bin/wwwjdic.cgi?9MHJ%8E%84%82%CD%8B%D9%92%A3%82%B5%82%B7%82%AC%82%C4%81A%82%BF%82%E7%82%C1%82%C6%8C%A9%82%E9%82%B1%82%C6%82%B7%82%E7%8Fo%97%88%82%DC%82%B9%82%F1%82%C5%82%B5%82%BD) it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

「緊張しすぎる」＝「緊張」 + 「する」 +「すぎる」

In order to combine the two verbs する and すぎる, you need to change the first one する into its [連用形]{れんようけい} (continuative form).

The 連用形 of the verb 「する」 is 「し」.  Since 「する」 is the most often used verb in the language, 「し」 is very important and you will keep seeing it from now on.

緊張しすぎる = to get too nervous

[飲]{の}みすぎる = to drink too much

[回答]{かいとう}しすぎる = to answer too many questions

Answer (score 4):

緊張し is　連用形(ますform) of the verb "緊張する".

Answer (score 3):

[緊張]{きんちょう} by itself is a [noun](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/59548/m0u/%E7%B7%8A%E5%BC%B5/). The English word "nervous" is an adjective.

To say the sentence in English, you would say "I was too nervous" or "I am too nervous." That makes the English construction a be-verb construction to apply the adjective to the subject.

To accomplish the same sort of thing -- to apply 緊張 to a subject in Japanese, you say 
 [緊張]{きんちょう}**する**。 This is roughly equal to "I am nervous."

The し you are parsing is a form of the verb する that conjugates with すぎる to give the meaning we would say in English with: "I was too nervous"

---

I do actually hear people drop the し sometimes in colloquial patterns and just say 緊張すぎる. In those contexts, I somewhat wonder if the meaning is that the person saying it is nervous or they believe the situation itself to be nervous.

Comment: Despite the root of the English word, I think there is a difference between "exceedingly~" and "too~".  If you look up "exceedingly" you will find something like 「非常に, とても, 大いに；特別に, 抜群に. 」. If you look up ~すぎる you will find something like 「度を越える」which means "to go over (exceed) the limit", not "exceedingly".

Comment: @Tim I don't really see the meaning difference you're claiming and I'm a native speaker of AmE. Maybe there's some sort of difference between your BrE and AmE? I only hear a formality difference. But I am also not especially attached to the wording. If there's something you prefer, go ahead and edit it.

Comment: Ok. Tx. Please see my edit. My Oxford American dictionary has "exceedingly" as "extremely", which does not necessarily mean "so nervous that you cannot do~". The only place I have seen "exceedingly" become "too" is in the OP's link.

Comment: That seems fine to me.